# Pie Chart does not work with Json Data using AngularJS and nvd3

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, nvd3.js

Problem,

I want to display the pie chart using the dynamic data from API but it does not work at all. Where as if i have a hard coded data it works perfectly fine.

I have created a Plunker

```
 <nvd3-pie-chart
        data="exampleDataPieChart"
        id="toolTipExample2"
        x="xFunction()"
        y="yFunction()"
        width="150"
        tooltips="true">
    </nvd3-pie-chart>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ve9X22X7RAuRGpA74tiB?p=preview

I am using github API and want to draw the pie chart for the languages used in the user repository

Please have a look and let me know where i am doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Zi5oYUvH0UcszMHtIv8n?p=preview)

2 things: your JSON format doesn't match `exampleDataPieChart`, as well as AngularJS doesn't know when to run `$scope.$apply()` internally.

Fix #1: Match the formats

```
var exampleDataPieChart = [{"key":"One","y":5},{"key":"Two","y":2},{"key":"Seven","y":9}]
```

vs.

```
var collectedData = [{"key":["JavaScript","CSS"],"y":[142531,205009]}]
```

Fix #2: Let AngularJS know you've updated data by creating a local `var data` then once its' ready, trigger `$scope.$apply()` by running `$scope.collectedData = data`.

Comment: Thanks Morgan :) have been trying for hours

Comment: Can you explain or point to something that explains why we need Fix2? I thought that by pushing new items to $scope.collectedData, the $apply would be triggered automatically?

Comment: @JoaoLeal Yeah for some reason `$scope.collectedData.push()` wasn't updating the data, so just storing it in a temporary var and then using `$scope.collectedData = tempvar` seemed to work. I'm guessing that using `.push()` doesn't trigger `$scope.$apply()` internally. Not sure.